# OpenMP properly declaring variables

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, g++, openmp

I'm completely new to OpenMP and parallelization, so while this problem is likely very simple, I'm not sure what's causing it or how to search for the solution. My code is:

```
int FindPrime(int size) {
    long long next_p = 2;
    #pragma omp parallel \
        shared(next_p,size)
    long long tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    long long tnum = omp_get_num_threads();
    for(int long long i = tid; i < size; i=i+tnum) {
        long long j;
        j=next_p+1;
         while (!IsPrime(j)) {
            j++;
        }
        next_p = j;
    }
    return next_p;
}
```

There is also a main function which calls `FindPrime`, and `isPrime` which checks whether or not a number is prime.

When I try compiling this code with g++ and the flags `-fopenmp` and `-lpthread`, I get the result

```
error: 'tid' was not declared in this scope
```

pointing to the line

```
for(int long long i = tid; i < size; i=i+tnum){
```

It's also strange to me that it only complains about `tid`, and not `tnum`, which also comes from an OpenMP function.

Comment: Add `{` and `}` to define the scope of your `parallel` region

Comment: The functions from the OpenMP runtime library just functions as any other. They can be called outside of parallel regions or other OpenMP constructs too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you face comes from the scope of the `parallel` directive you wrote. Since you didn't use `{` and `}` to create a block defining its scope, this one is apparently restricted to the single line that follows it, namely

```
long long tid = omp_get_thread_num();
```

So your `tid` variable has now a scope of only one line (its declaration) and is therefore not declared when you want to use it in the `for` loop.

To fix the issue, you only need to add the `{` and `}` to mark the parallel block, like this:

```
int FindPrime(int size) {
    long long next_p = 2;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(next_p,size)
    { // start of the parallel block
        long long tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        long long tnum = omp_get_num_threads();
        for(long long i = tid; i < size; i=i+tnum) {
            long long j;
            j=next_p+1;
            while (!IsPrime(j)) {
                j++;
            }
            next_p = j;
        }
    } // end of the parallel block
    return next_p;
}
```

This way, you will have your code parallelized. However, I'm not sure what it is supposed to do, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do what you expect it to... Indeed, you have a race condition on the update of `next_p` between the threads. I believe you should rethink your algorithm.

Finally, your way of parallelizing the `for` loop is exactly like using `#pragma omp for schedule( static, 1 )`. You should probably consider using it if yo want to stick to this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. I actually found the race condition once I got the code compiled and running, and ended up going about this problem differently. I've heard of omp for loops, but schedule is new to me. thanks for the insight.

Comment: There is no such requirement in the OpenMP specification to enclose the scope of executable directives within curly braces. _"**structured block** - For C/C++, an executable statement, possibly compound, with a single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom, or an OpenMP construct."_ The code of the OP is valid OpenMP, though not what s/he expects, and the parallel region consists of the single statement following the directive.

Comment: The previous comment relates to your statement _"... (which is BTW non-standard and should have been reported as erroneous by your compiler) ..."_, which is incorrect.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I like to use and abuse the comma operator to pack as many operations as possible right after an OpenMP pragma to avoid having to use curly braces.

Comment: @HristoIliev my bad. I checked and you're correct (as always). I removed the faulty sentence. That said, I thought it was like this because I remember getting errors from compilers for doing exactly that, which was annoying since it was forcing me to add curly brackets for no reasons. then I went checking on the standard and saw the _structured block_ references and thought they were only curly bracket-enclosed ones... Again, my mistake.